# Get UITableViewIndex frame

Tags: ios, uitableview

How to get frame of UITableViewIndex of a UITableView, I have searched and read documentation but there is no direct method

I tried this code to find about subviews

```
var recursionLevel: Int = 0

func listSubviews(_ view: UIView) {
    self.recursionLevel += 1
    view.subviews.forEach { (subview) in
        var str = " "
        for  _ in 1...self.recursionLevel {
            str += " "
        }
        print("****\(str)subview: \(type(of:subview)) frame ", subview.frame)
        listSubviews(subview)

    }
    self.recursionLevel -= 1
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After listing all UITableView subviews found that UITableViewIndex is the last subview, so to get section index view it would just be `self.tableView.subviews.last`

Comment: Never rely on this. This could change during any iOS update.

Comment: @rmaddy I agree with you, but apple didn't give a formal way to do it, are there any safe way ?

Comment: Why do you need the frame of the section indexes?

Comment: @rmaddy something like https://itunes.apple.com/lc/app/masjid-timetable/id461959243?mt=8, to set auto layout constraints.